# Countdowntimer onTick method not displaying proper seconds

Tags: java, android

For my code I use a countdown timer, however I add seconds to it as after they get an answer correct, the timer is reset to 5 seconds. The problem with this is that the text that displays the time still has the wrong number, it doesn't repeat digits. For instance if it was a 5 second timer and it goes 5,4,3 then the user gets it right, the time will go 3, 3, 3, 2, 1. 
Here is my countdown code

```
n = 5000;
time = new TextView(this);
time.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    timer = new CountDownTimer(n, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           time.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Intent endIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Endgame.class);
            endIntent.putExtra("rounds",round);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(endIntent);
        }

    }.start();
```

Then if the user gets the question right - this is the part that restarts it

```
 if(person == false){
     picturechanger();
     n=5000;
     timer.onTick(5000);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if(person == false){
 picturechanger();
 n=5000; // Not sure why u put n=5000 here..?
 if(timer != null)
     timer.cancel();
 timer.start();
```

}

Comment: If this code is not your final solution: Check also if you are running multiple timers at the same time. They will all access the same TextView and repeating your output like 333222111...